# Subjonctif passé, ou autre chose ? Exemple de phrase, aide à la correction

Tags: conjugaison, subjonctif

Voilà une phrase et j'aimerais savoir quelle différence cela induirait si je choisissais un temps plutôt qu'un autre :

> Assise dehors, elle avait attendu patiemment, jusqu’à ce qu’il ait
>   apporté ...

J'avais aussi pensé écrire :

> Assise dehors, elle avait attendu patiemment. Puis, il apporta...

Pour remettre le lecteur dans le contexte, il s'agit d'un passage flash back écrit au passé composé / imparfait. Les phrases d'avant et d'après sont à ces temps là. Par contre la construction de cette phrase me pose problème. 
Avez vous une idée ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Phrase 1**

> Assise dehors, elle avait attendu patiemment, jusqu’à ce qu’il ait apporté ...

On a une principale au passé (plus-que parfait) et une subordonnée au subjonctif passé.
 Le choix du subjonctif dans la subordonnée implique une idée d'incertitude quant au résultat. En effet, la locution conjonctive *jusqu'à ce que* peut être suivit soit du subjonctif, soit de l'indicatif. Elle « est généralement suivie d’un verbe au subjonctif, puisqu’elle implique souvent une idée d’incertitude ou de finalité. Toutefois, si on veut insister sur l’aspect réel d’un fait, il est possible de mettre le verbe qui suit à l’indicatif; cet emploi est cependant plus courant dans la langue littéraire.» [BDL](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=4320)

Le *Robert des difficultés* dit que « l'indicatif après *jusqu'à ce que* est correct quand la subordonnée ne comporte pas d'idée de but non encore atteint ou d'incertitude quant au résultat. »

Grevisse dit que « l'emploi de l'indicatif de l'indicatif après *jusqu'à ce que* est, dans l'usage moderne, moins rare qu'on ne croirait ; il faut souhaiter qu'il s'étende, parce qu'il permet de marquer une précision utile. Par exemple, dans la phrase suivante, de Malraux  *Il avait combattu jusqu'à ce qu'il fut tué*, le subjonctif semble marquer, assez curieusement, un but à atteindre ; or c'est simplement une limite de temps qu'il s'agissait d'indiquer dans la réalité des faits, et c'est pourquoi l'indicatif *fut* tué aurait été parfaitement justifié. »

Bien que ne proposiez pas cet emploi de l'indicatif je tenais à vous le signaler, et l'exemple trouvé dans Grevisse est très semblable au vôtre.

Si vous voulez rendre la seconde action plus réelle il faudrait employer l'indicatif, ce qui avec la principale au plus-que-parfait implique le passé simple ou le passé antérieur :

- Assise dehors, elle avait attendu patiemment, jusqu’à ce qu’il apporta/qu'il eut apporté...

**Phrase 2**

> Assise dehors, elle avait attendu patiemment. Puis, il apporta...

On a deux propositions indépendantes, la première est au plus-que-parfait, la suivante est au passé simple. Le choix du plus-que-parfait dans la première permet d'insister sur la durée de l'action. Le passé simple de la phrase suivante reflète une action brève qui vient se greffer sur un moment de la première (qui peut ou non se prolonger au-delà de cette interruption).

Si vraiment vous voulez rendre la deuxième action plus présente dans le récit il faut choisir le passé simple, soit en subordonnée avec *jusqu'à*, soit avec une deuxième proposition indépendante comme dans la phrase 2.

Comment: Wow merci Laure. Je dois encore re étudier votre réponse pour savoir quelle option je dois choisir mais c'est exactement ce que j'espérais. Merci beaucoup.

Comment: petite précision maintenant que j'ai étudié plus en détail et à tête reposée votre réponse. Il n'est donc pas fondamentalement de mettre du passé simple ou du présent de l'indicatif après jusqu'à ce que...? est-ce le cas pour d'autres "mots" suivi normalement du subjonctif ?

Comment: @MarineGalantin Je pense que vous vouliez dire fondamentalement faux ? En grammaire, il y a des règles (souvent anciennes et qui ne reflètent pas l'évolution de la langue) et la langue telle que la parlent et l'écrivent les gens de nos jours. [Grevisse](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Le_Bon_Usage) a observé et décrit les usages mais rappelle aussi les prescriptions de l'Académie Française, il y a un fort consensus autour de sa grammaire (déjà ancienne mais mise à jour régulièrement) mais il y a en France des gens qui n'admettent que difficilement que la langue évolue.

Comment: À l'école primaire en France et dans l'enseignement du français aux étrangers (du moins jusqu'au niveau B2 du CECRL) les enseignants ont tendance à rester normatifs par souci de simplicité pédagogique je suppose. Votre niveau de français ayant l'air excellent, j'ai pensé que vous pourriez affronter le problème. « est-ce le cas pour d'autres "mots" suivi normalement du subjonctif ? » Certainement, mais je pense que trouver une liste serait difficile, il me semble plus judicieux de se poser la question au cas par cas,

Comment: et de raisonner en se disant que le choix de l'indicatif ou du subjonctif dépend de ce qu'on veut exprimer. Il y a bien sûr des mots après lesquels le subjonctif s'impose, par exemple (du moins pour moi) *afin que* qui ne peut qu'introduire une action sur laquelle plane l'incertitude entraîne le subjonctif. Pour résumer la question est complexe. [Par exemple](https://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2guides/guides/chroniq/index-fra.html?lang=fra&lettr=indx_titls&page=9U66xqoK0nJk.html)

Answer (score -1):

La première formulation doit comprendre dans la subordonnée un verbe au subjonctif ([BDL](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?t1=1&id=4238)) ; il est exigé par la locution conjonctive et ce n'est que cette locution qui amène un changement en comparaison de ce que la seconde formulation exprime. Le temps me semble immatériel dans cette question.
Dans la seconde formulation, qui utilise le passé simple, il n'y a pas de connexion entre l'attente et un évènement qui y met fin; peut-être que son attente continue, peut être qu'elle prend fin à ce moment précis où quelque chose est apporté.
Je ne vois pas de difficultés. Essayez de fournir des explications aussi complètes que possibles et attendez d'autres réponses.

Comment: Non! Le mode n'est **en aucun cas exigé**. Il est tout à fait possible de choisir l'indicatif si on souhaite insister sur l'aspect reel.

Comment: @aCOSwt La BDL ne voit pas les choses selon la bonne optique alors ? J'ai eu des problèmes dernièrement lorsque je disais qu'après « bien que » on n'a pas à utiliser le subjonctif ; on m'a répondu qu'il ne fallait chercher aucune justification à l'emploi de ce mode et que *c'était comme ça* (user petitrien, qui a une bonne pratique du langage).

Comment: *Bien que* et *jusqu'à ce que* n'ont pas le même sens et donc leur relation au virtuel (le subjonctif est le mode utilisé pour exprimer une action envisagée, pas forcément accomplie) est différente.  Cependant, même avec *bien que* on utilise parfois l'indicatif. Voir [cet article](https://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2guides/guides/chroniq/index-fra.html?lang=fra&lettr=indx_titls&page=9U66xqoK0nJk.html) qui résume bien la situation pour *bien que*. Bien entendu chacun est libre de ses choix linguistiques, mais vouloir les imposer aux autres peut être discutable.

Comment: @Laure Dans cette discussion il est tout simplement question de la BDL, laquelle affirme que le subjonctif est toujours nécessaire après « jusqu'à ce que » mais pas d'autre chose, et cela est contredit catégoriquement par user **aCoswt**.

Comment: Ah la BDL affirme ? [Ce n'est pas ce que je lis](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=4320). Le fait est que la question est discutée, qu'il y a les pour et les contre et qu'être trop affirmatif (cf. « il est exigé ») sans tenir compte de l'usage et sans varier ses sources c'est prendre un parti pris non partagé par tous. La langue ça se parle aussi et beaucoup de locuteurs natifs francophones ont un regard critique quand quelque chose leur parait étrange qui les oblige à chercher ailleurs que la première source venue .

Comment: @Laure Leur information n'est pas consistante ; sur cette page il n'y a rien d'autre : http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?t1=1&id=4238

Comment: C'est parce que ce sont des personnes différentes qui ont fait les pages, c'est normal vu qu'il existe plusieurs points de vue. Quand on connaît la langue on sait qu'il y a plusieurs points de vue et on les cherche, on ne croit pas le premier venu sur parole.